# Trying to get different percentage count ata a time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to get different counts at a time for making different skills percentage progress bars. [This is UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1gR9.png). But it always gives one count, I don't know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
const advantageObj = [
    {
      title: "HTML",
      img: images.htmlIcon,
      count: 50
    },
    {
      title: "Wordpress",
      img: images.wordpress,
      count: 50
    },
    {
      title: "Elementor",
      img: images.elementor,
      count: 50
    },
    {
      title: "Ebay",
      img: images.ebay,
      count: 89
    },
    {
      title: "JavaScript",
      img: images.js,
      count: 50
    },
    {
      title: "CSS",
      img: images.css,
      count: 78
    }
  ]
```

Here is the code.

```
  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const integer = advantageObj.map(int => int.count);


  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < integer.length; i++) {
        if (count < integer[i]) {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }
      };
    }, 50);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Here is JSX for the component.

```
 <div>
      <h1 className="section-title">Advantages</h1>
      <div className="advContainer">
        {advantageObj.map((item, index) =>
          <div key={index} className="advItems">
            <h1>
              <img src={item.img} alt="" />
              <div class="progress-done">
                <span className="progress-count">{count}%</span>
              </div>
              {item.title}
            </h1>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if i understood your question correctly, but i try to answer it.

I think your problem is that you use one state variable for all counters. By doing that, your counters will always show the same percentage value.
Try to provide an own state variable to each counter.

Edit as a reply to your answer:
You could provide the state variable inside your advantageObj. That way, you can also map out the state variable. So create a state variable for each type, e.g. const [htmlCount, setHtmlCount] = useState();
and pass it into your advantageObj.

```
const [htmlCount, setHtmlCount] = useState();
const [wordpressCount, setWordpressCount] = useState();
const [elementorCount, setElementorCount] = useState();

    const advantageObj = [
        {
          title: "HTML",
          img: images.htmlIcon,
          count: 50,
          stateVar: htmlCount,
        },
        {
          title: "Wordpress",
          img: images.wordpress,
          count: 50,
          stateVar: wordpressCount,
        },
        {
          title: "Elementor",
          img: images.elementor,
          count: 50,
          stateVar: elementorCount,
        },
        ...
      ]
```

And then inside your map function, point to that stateVar:

```
<div className="advContainer">
        {advantageObj.map((item, index) =>
          <div key={index} className="advItems">
            <h1>
              <img src={item.img} alt="" />
              <div class="progress-done">
                <span className="progress-count">{item.stateVar}%</span>
              </div>
              {item.title}
            </h1>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
```

If you then set a new value to these state variables, only the one counter should change. :)

Comment: Yes, you understood. But how do I assign it to every state, after mapping?

Comment: Please have a look at the "Edit" inside my original reply :)